# Resizing bucket of hashmap

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Performance of hashmap depends on Load factor(l) and Capacity(c). If the number of entries in a map are greater than or equal to (l*c) it changes the internal data structures i.e increases the capacity or size of bucket. My question is how does it calculate the number of entries in a hashmap to check the mentioned condition? Is it the total number of (key, value) pairs in map or the number of engaged locations in the bucket being used? If it's the number of engaged locations in bucket how do you keep track of those? I’m assuming chaining is being followed to avoid collisions.

Comment: If you have not yet, have a look at the source code for HashMap: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: Hi @copeg . I have read the article. Wanted to know why we resize the bucket when have (load factor * capacity) number of key value pairs in our map and not when have (load factor * capacity) numbers of bucket locations occupied?

Answer (score 1):

The `load factor` is the ratio of `the number of elements` it holds and your HashMap `capacity` (i.e. how many buckets you have)

So using a simple `array` of `10 spaces` with a load factor of `.75` means that the moment your elements divided by your size is greater or equal to `75%` (that will mean there are 8 elements in your Array), the data structure must regrow in order to lower the ratio.

The HashMap usually keeps track of the `number of elements` it holds on every `add/remove` operation and recalculates the `load factor`

Comment: That's the case where bucket is the simple array and you save the value directly in the bucket location(array index) you obtained from your hashcode. What if I'm chaining? If two different keys gives the same bucket location then I start a linkedlist from that bucket location where nodes save both the key and value. Thus for these two (key, value) pairs only one location at bucket is used which holds both the (key, value) pair in form of linkedlist.